# Override behavior for UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a UIActivityViewController which currently displays "Save Image" as the first option on the bottom rail. I have some custom code for saving an image to a custom folder, and I would also like to use this code for the UIActivityViewController option UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll. Is it possible to override or modify the behavior of the UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll without creating a custom UIActivity? If not, then is there a way to assign priority of UIActivities so that my custom version of Save Image is still shown first in the list of activities?

Comment: Sorry but no and no.

Comment: @rmaddy you should make this the answer, because it is true ;)